# RBAC: access denied when request in kubeflow notebooks

Tags: kubeflow, istio-sidecar

I tried the kserve example and faced the problem of `RBAC: Access Denied`.

1. **add user**

   ```
   $ kubectl -n auth edit cm dex
   ```

   add example infomation in `staticPasswords`

   ```
       - email: my_email@gmail.com
         hash: my_ps_hash
         userID: "myuserid"
         username: myusername
   ```

   ```
   $ kubectl rollout restart deployment dex -n auth
   ```
2. **add profile for create namespace**

   ```
   $ vi profile.yaml
   ```

   ```
   apiVersion: kubeflow.org/v1beta1
   kind: Profile
   metadata:
     name: test-namespace
   spec:
     owner:
       kind: User
       name: my_email@gmail.com
     resourceQuotaSpec: {}
   ```

   ```
   kubectl apply -f profile.yaml
   ```
3. **Serving exam model**

   `kubeflow Central Dashboard` - `Models` - `+NEW MODEL SERVER`

   ```
   apiVersion: "serving.kserve.io/v1beta1"
   kind: "InferenceService"
   metadata:
     annotations:
       isdecar.istio.is/inject: "false"
     name: "sklearn-iris"
   spec:
     predictor:
       sklearn:
         image: "kserve/sklearnserver:v0.9.0"
         storageUri: "gs://kfserving-examples/models/sklearn/1.0/model"
   ```

   ```
   $ kubectl get InferenceService -n test-namespace
   ```

   ```
   NAME                 URL                                                      READY   PREV   LATEST   PREVROLLEDOUTREVISION   LATESTREADYREVISION                          AGE
   sklearn-iris   http://sklearn-iris-test2.test-namespace.example.com   True           100                              sklearn-iris-predictor-default-00001   81m
   ```

   READY: `True`
4. **Add New Notebook**

   `kubeflow Central Dashboard` - `Notebooks` - `+New Notebook`

   and run code

   ```py
   from kserve import (utils, KServeClient)
   import requests
   import json

   sklear_iris_input = dict(instances = [
           [6.8, 2.8, 4.8, 1.4],
           [6.0, 3.4, 4.5, 1.6]
       ])

   namespace = utils.get_default_target_namespace()     # Get namespace.  It's worked
   service_name = "sklearn-iris"

   kserve = KServeClient()
   isvc_resp = kserve.get(service_name, namespace = namespace)      # It's worked
   # http://sklearn-iris.test-namespace.svc.cluster.local/v1/models/sklearn-iris-test2:predict
   isvc_url = isvc_resp['status']['address']['url'] 

   response = requests.post(isvc_url, json = json.dumps(sklear_iris_input))        

   print(response.text)
   ```

   ```
   RBAC: access denied
   ```

- env:

  `kserve`: 0.9.0

  `kubeflow`: 1.6.0

  `kubernetes`: v1.22.13 and run **master node**(already disable taint)

Why is this message(`RBAC: access denied`) occurring?

Your help is of great help to me. Help me!

Comment: "RBAC denied" is an istio auth error, check if authorization policy at the target is allowing source? source here would be istio gateway as per my understanding